# ui-router url parameter with hashtag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on the routing of my angular application, but I can't seem to find the following:

`example.com/#parameter`

In this url the #parameter should stay #parameter and get the param data. Now it removes the # and goes to `example.com/parameter`

If I go to `example.com/#parameter` it should do the same as it would if I go to `example.com/parameter`

I have the following in my app.js

```
 url: "/:bandName"
```

and send this data to my controller with $stateParams

Is there any way to keep the hashtag in the url ?

-- edit

so here is some code that works on enter with `/#parameter`

```
        $urlRouterProvider.when(':#bandName', '/:bandName')
                .otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider.state('appband', {
                    url: "/:bandName",
                    templateUrl: "main.php",
                    controller: 'mainController'
        })

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

With this if I go to `example.com/#randomBandName` I get redirected to `example.com/randomBandName`and I get *randomBandName* as parameter in my controller

So what I need is on enter that `example.com/#randomBandName` stays `example.com/#randomBandName` and that I still get *randomBandName* in my controller.

But when I remove `$urlRouterProvider.when(':#bandName', '/:bandName')` I just get an empty page.

Comment: Are you using ``$locationProvider``?

Comment: yes i'm using `$locationProvider`

Comment: Could you add that and how to your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that look suspect with this:

#### trailing slash

Are you using HTML5 mode for your URLs?  I'd suggest using this URL setup `url: "/parameter"` if you indeed see `param` as more of a resource.

You might also read this - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes

#### query param

If you are intending `param` to be a *query parameter* then you need this..

`url: "/?parameter"`

more on that here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters

Comment: Well, the parameter can be any given band that's in the database, on enter it gets redirected to that bands music. 
It works without a hashtag atm.

Comment: Are these supposed to be RESTful URLs?  Like `/bands/{band_name}` or are you trying to go `/bands?{band_name}`.  Either way, the change is trivial in terms of the ui.router _state_